# Need examples on how to use Postman's Newman with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postman, newman

The Library section on this [page](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro) shows how to run a Postman collection passing an Options object as argument. Where can I find documentation. I'm using the 2.x release. Where can I find more documentation on using Newman with Nodejs? Specifically, what are all the possible members of the Options object? Do they cover all the Newman command line options? And how to use the responseHandler member?
I tried looking into https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/tree/release/2.x but didn't find useful documentation except for the readme.md file.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Usage" section of the documentation for the Newman NPM package you can find an example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#usage

Answer (score -1):

you may have a looke at this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options

It's quite exhaustive ...
hope this helps